# using webview2 in Winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, webview, webbrowser-control, webview2

I am new to webview2, I have a problem in adding some html elements to a table in html using executeScriptAsync
this is C# Code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeAsync();
        
    }
    private async void  InitializeAsync()
    {
        var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(userDataFolder: Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MarkdownMonster_Browser"));
        
        await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
        webView21.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded;
        webView21.Source = new Uri(@"C:\Users\kjanky\Desktop\ChatWindowHTML.html");
        string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\kjanky\Desktop\New Text Document.txt");
        
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);
        
        webView21.CoreWebView2.OpenDevToolsWindow();
    }

    private async void CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded(object sender, CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Now it's safe to interact with the DOM
        string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\kjanky\Desktop\New Text Document.txt");
        s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);
        await  webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync($"addMessageRowNew({s})");

    }
}
```

document that I want to add to table in html:(I read it from a txt file)

```html
   <tr id='202111241525440369' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu("202111241525440369");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu("202111241525440369");'><td class='td_left noselect' nowrap='nowrap' align='right' draggable='false' ><IMG class='theimage' draggable='false' src='C:\Users\kjanky\AppData\Local\Viva_Client\387608\History\ThumbProfPics\RoundWithoutStatus\387283.png'></td><td class='td_center' id='Forward202111241525440369' style='table-layout:fixed;'><div class='noselect' style='color: DarkGray; text-align:left; font-size: 11px; '>khaled, 03:25 PM</div><div  id='menu202111241525440369' class='bubble-left' oncontextmenu='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2","زززز", "202111241525440369");' ><P style='table-layout:fixed;  text-align:right;'>زززز </p></div><div style='float:right;'><img id='pnt202111241525440369' class='noselect' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAFtJREFUKFNj+P//P8kYq2BuXqEAEAdgkwNhrIJADReA+D8ujRgCIAxUnADVKIBNHkOAGIxVkCyboBpI9hNZoQfSVIBNDoSxCgI1wJyHVSOGAAgDFdMpyPHj/wwAaF7b+svPFkkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;'  onclick='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2", "زززز", "202111241525440369");' /></div></td><td style='width:17px;' valign='top' align='left'><img style='margin-top: 3px;visibility:hidden;display:none;' id='read202111241525440369' draggable='false' class='noselect' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAIRJREFUKFOVj0ERgDAMBCuhJvhXAhKQgAQkIAEJvFGBBCzgoA5CjmmYQDIUHju9Xm8fDUT0G7es4ZY13LKGWwrNsicmM6vKozsGagR6lZMMWiaqLAIxU8mngI1IeNyYWLJgBC3NjIgiIBvhkh4iwMdxGgHcLjzAh7uSB08ApviCW75D4QBh7dcJ7Ox/ngAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='/></td></tr><tr id='202111241525479513' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu("202111241525479513");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu("202111241525479513");'><td class='td_left noselect' nowrap='nowrap' align='right' draggable='false' ></td><td class='td_center' id='Forward202111241525479513' style='table-layout:fixed;'><div class='noselect' style='color: DarkGray; text-align:right; font-size: 11px; '>03:25 PM</div><div  id='menu202111241525479513' class='bubble-right' oncontextmenu='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2","bvjvjv\r\n\u0026#160;", "202111241525479513");' ><P style='table-layout:fixed; '>bvjvjv
<BR>&#160; </p></div><div style='float:left;'><img id='pnt202111241525479513' class='noselect' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAFtJREFUKFNj+P//P8kYq2BuXqEAEAdgkwNhrIJADReA+D8ujRgCIAxUnADVKIBNHkOAGIxVkCyboBpI9hNZoQfSVIBNDoSxCgI1wJyHVSOGAAgDFdMpyPHj/wwAaF7b+svPFkkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;'  onclick='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2", "bvjvjv\r\n\u0026#160;", "202111241525479513");' /></div></td><td style='width:17px;' valign='top' align='left'><img style='margin-top: 3px;' id='read202111241525479513' draggable='false' class='noselect' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAIBJREFUKFOVz1ENgDAMBFAkTMokIAEJMwABB0hAEhKQgAQclF6yI4U1DD5echy9EBoR+c0ta9yyxi1r3JL6YYrqUKvJs3sM5kjUkjNEHrQqmAzuADcc4eWmQs5UDOwoKQ75hd3kloNr9BgCfpw52QHcHvSgg5xH5qei+MIt30lzAsg5wpO5/4C8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'/></td></tr><tr id='202111241530039530' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu("202111241530039530");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu("202111241530039530");'><td class='td_left noselect' nowrap='nowrap' align='right' draggable='false' ><IMG class='theimage' draggable='false' src='C:\Users\kjanky\AppData\Local\Viva_Client\387608\History\ThumbProfPics\RoundWithoutStatus\387283.png'></td><td class='td_center' id='Forward202111241530039530' style='table-layout:fixed;'><div class='noselect' style='color: DarkGray; text-align:left; font-size: 11px; '>khaled, 03:30 PM</div><div  id='menu202111241530039530' class='bubble-left' oncontextmenu='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2","تن", "202111241530039530");' ><P style='table-layout:fixed;  text-align:right;'>تن </p></div><div style='float:right;'><img id='pnt202111241530039530' class='noselect' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAFtJREFUKFNj+P//P8kYq2BuXqEAEAdgkwNhrIJADReA+D8ujRgCIAxUnADVKIBNHkOAGIxVkCyboBpI9hNZoQfSVIBNDoSxCgI1wJyHVSOGAAgDFdMpyPHj/wwAaF7b+svPFkkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;'  onclick='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2", "تن", "202111241530039530");' /></div></td><td style='width:17px;' valign='top' align='left'><img style='margin-top: 3px;visibility:hidden;display:none;' id='read202111241530039530' draggable='false' class='noselect' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAIRJREFUKFOVj0ERgDAMBCuhJvhXAhKQgAQkIAEJvFGBBCzgoA5CjmmYQDIUHju9Xm8fDUT0G7es4ZY13LKGWwrNsicmM6vKozsGagR6lZMMWiaqLAIxU8mngI1IeNyYWLJgBC3NjIgiIBvhkh4iwMdxGgHcLjzAh7uSB08ApviCW75D4QBh7dcJ7Ox/ngAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='/></td></tr><tr id='202111241543074933' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu("202111241543074933");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu("202111241543074933");'><td class='td_left noselect' nowrap='nowrap' align='right' draggable='false' ></td><td class='td_center' id='Forward202111241543074933' style='table-layout:fixed;'><div class='noselect' style='color: DarkGray; text-align:right; font-size: 11px; '>03:43 PM</div><div  id='menu202111241543074933' class='bubble-right' oncontextmenu='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2","bbybyb\r\n\u0026#160;", "202111241543074933");' ><P style='table-layout:fixed; '>bbybyb
<BR>&#160; </p></div><div style='float:left;'><img id='pnt202111241543074933' class='noselect' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAFtJREFUKFNj+P//P8kYq2BuXqEAEAdgkwNhrIJADReA+D8ujRgCIAxUnADVKIBNHkOAGIxVkCyboBpI9hNZoQfSVIBNDoSxCgI1wJyHVSOGAAgDFdMpyPHj/wwAaF7b+svPFkkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;'  onclick='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2", "bbybyb\r\n\u0026#160;", "202111241543074933");' /></div></td><td style='width:17px;' valign='top' align='left'><img style='margin-top: 3px;' id='read202111241543074933' draggable='false' class='noselect' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAIRJREFUKFOVj0ERgDAMBCuhJvhXAhKQgAQkIAEJvFGBBCzgoA5CjmmYQDIUHju9Xm8fDUT0G7es4ZY13LKGWwrNsicmM6vKozsGagR6lZMMWiaqLAIxU8mngI1IeNyYWLJgBC3NjIgiIBvhkh4iwMdxGgHcLjzAh7uSB08ApviCW75D4QBh7dcJ7Ox/ngAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='/></td></tr><tr id='202111241547089154' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu("202111241547089154");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu("202111241547089154");'><td class='td_left noselect' nowrap='nowrap' align='right' draggable='false' ></td><td class='td_center' id='Forward202111241547089154' style='table-layout:fixed;'><div class='noselect' style='color: DarkGray; text-align:right; font-size: 11px; '>03:47 PM</div><div  id='menu202111241547089154' class='bubble-right' oncontextmenu='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2","hyhyhyh\r\n\u0026#160;", "202111241547089154");' ><P style='table-layout:fixed; '>hyhyhyh
<BR>&#160; </p></div><div style='float:left;'><img id='pnt202111241547089154' class='noselect' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAFtJREFUKFNj+P//P8kYq2BuXqEAEAdgkwNhrIJADReA+D8ujRgCIAxUnADVKIBNHkOAGIxVkCyboBpI9hNZoQfSVIBNDoSxCgI1wJyHVSOGAAgDFdMpyPHj/wwAaF7b+svPFkkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;'  onclick='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2", "hyhyhyh\r\n\u0026#160;", "202111241547089154");' /></div></td><td style='width:17px;' valign='top' align='left'><img style='margin-top: 3px;' id='read202111241547089154' draggable='false' class='noselect' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAIBJREFUKFOVz1ENgDAMBFAkTMokIAEJMwABB0hAEhKQgAQclF6yI4U1DD5echy9EBoR+c0ta9yyxi1r3JL6YYrqUKvJs3sM5kjUkjNEHrQqmAzuADcc4eWmQs5UDOwoKQ75hd3kloNr9BgCfpw52QHcHvSgg5xH5qei+MIt30lzAsg5wpO5/4C8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'/></td></tr><tr><td class='td_left' nowrap='nowrap' align='right'></td> <td style='width: 85%;'><div style='height: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #DFDFDF;text-align:center;'><div class='abc' style='visibility:visible;display:block;'><span style='margin-bottom: 50px;  color:#8A8D91 ;font-size: 12px; background-color:white; padding: 0 10px;'>Thursday</span></div><div class='abc_ar' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;'><span style='margin-bottom: 50px; color:#8A8D91 ;font-size: 12px; background-color :white; padding: 0 10px;'>الخميس</span></div></div></td><td class='td_right' align='right'></td></tr><tr id='202111250819044130' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu("202111250819044130");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu("202111250819044130");'><td class='td_left noselect' nowrap='nowrap' align='right' draggable='false' ></td><td class='td_center' id='Forward202111250819044130' style='table-layout:fixed;'><div class='noselect' style='color: DarkGray; text-align:right; font-size: 11px; '>08:19 AM</div><div  id='menu202111250819044130' class='bubble-right' oncontextmenu='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2","vrgrrggr\r\n\u0026#160;", "202111250819044130");' ><P style='table-layout:fixed; '>vrgrrggr
<BR>&#160; </p></div><div style='float:left;'><img id='pnt202111250819044130' class='noselect' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAFtJREFUKFNj+P//P8kYq2BuXqEAEAdgkwNhrIJADReA+D8ujRgCIAxUnADVKIBNHkOAGIxVkCyboBpI9hNZoQfSVIBNDoSxCgI1wJyHVSOGAAgDFdMpyPHj/wwAaF7b+svPFkkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;'  onclick='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2", "vrgrrggr\r\n\u0026#160;", "202111250819044130");' /></div></td><td style='width:17px;' valign='top' align='left'><img style='margin-top: 3px;' id='read202111250819044130' draggable='false' class='noselect' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAIRJREFUKFOVj0ERgDAMBCuhJvhXAhKQgAQkIAEJvFGBBCzgoA5CjmmYQDIUHju9Xm8fDUT0G7es4ZY13LKGWwrNsicmM6vKozsGagR6lZMMWiaqLAIxU8mngI1IeNyYWLJgBC3NjIgiIBvhkh4iwMdxGgHcLjzAh7uSB08ApviCW75D4QBh7dcJ7Ox/ngAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='/></td></tr><TR id='202111250819404750' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu("202111250819404750");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu("202111250819404750");'><td class='td_left' nowrap='nowrap' align='right' style='padding-top: 5px;'></td><td id='202111250819404750' class='td_center' style='table-layout:fixed;direction: rtl;' ><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><TR style='HEIGHT:10px; display: none;visibility: hidden;'><TD style='width:300px;' class='td_right'><div style='text-align:right; font-size: 11px;'>08:19 AM</div></TD><TD></TD></TR> <TR style='HEIGHT:36px;'><td style='display:inline-block;'><div id='SharedContact202111250819404750' class='SharedContact' dir='ltr' oncontextmenu='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#5", " ", "202111250819404750");'onclick="window.external.SharedContact_Click('Ahmed Khair J','','0096171803171;','','','')"><div class='ImageDiv'><img src='data:image/png;base64,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'  id ='SharedContactImage202111250819404750' class='SharedContactImage' ></div><div class='SharedContactInformation'><label id='SharedContactName202111250819404750' class='SharedContactName'>Ahmed Khair J </label></div><div class='HorizentalLineSeperator'></div><button id='SharedContactChatButton202111250819404750' class='SharedContactButtons' onclick="window.external.SharedContact_ChatButton(387187)">Chat</button><div id='VerticalLineSeperator202111250819404750' class='VerticalLineSeperator'></div><button id='SharedContactAddButton202111250819404750' class='SharedContactButtons' onclick="window.external.SharedContact_AddButton(387187, 387608,9511115,'','','Ahmed Khair J','')">Add</button><button id='SharedContactInviteButton202111250819404750' class='SharedContactInviteButton'>Inivite to VIVA Client</button></div><style>#SharedContactChatButton202111250819404750 {width: 100%;}#SharedContactAddButton202111250819404750 {display: none;}#VerticalLineSeperator202111250819404750{display: none;}#SharedContact202111250819404750 {background: #F4F4F7;}</style></td><td style='vertical-align:top;'><div style='float:left;'><img id='pnt202111250819404750' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAFtJREFUKFNj+P//P8kYq2BuXqEAEAdgkwNhrIJADReA+D8ujRgCIAxUnADVKIBNHkOAGIxVkCyboBpI9hNZoQfSVIBNDoSxCgI1wJyHVSOGAAgDFdMpyPHj/wwAaF7b+svPFkkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;' onclick='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#5", " ", "202111250819404750");' /></div></td></TR></table></td><td style='width:17px;' valign='top' align='left'><img id='read202111250819404750' style='margin-top: 3px;' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAIBJREFUKFOVz1ENgDAMBFAkTMokIAEJMwABB0hAEhKQgAQclF6yI4U1DD5echy9EBoR+c0ta9yyxi1r3JL6YYrqUKvJs3sM5kjUkjNEHrQqmAzuADcc4eWmQs5UDOwoKQ75hd3kloNr9BgCfpw52QHcHvSgg5xH5qei+MIt30lzAsg5wpO5/4C8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC' /></td></tr><tr id='202111251127394061' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu("202111251127394061");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu("202111251127394061");'><td class='td_left noselect' nowrap='nowrap' align='right' draggable='false' ></td><td class='td_center' id='Forward202111251127394061' style='table-layout:fixed;'><div class='noselect' style='color: DarkGray; text-align:right; font-size: 11px; '>11:27 AM</div><div  id='menu202111251127394061' class='bubble-right' oncontextmenu='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2","cfcfc\r\n\u0026#160;", "202111251127394061");' ><P style='table-layout:fixed; '>cfcfc
<BR>&#160; </p></div><div style='float:left;'><img id='pnt202111251127394061' class='noselect' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAFtJREFUKFNj+P//P8kYq2BuXqEAEAdgkwNhrIJADReA+D8ujRgCIAxUnADVKIBNHkOAGIxVkCyboBpI9hNZoQfSVIBNDoSxCgI1wJyHVSOGAAgDFdMpyPHj/wwAaF7b+svPFkkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;'  onclick='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2", "cfcfc\r\n\u0026#160;", "202111251127394061");' /></div></td><td style='width:17px;' valign='top' align='left'><img style='margin-top: 3px;' id='read202111251127394061' draggable='false' class='noselect' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAIRJREFUKFOVj0ERgDAMBCuhJvhXAhKQgAQkIAEJvFGBBCzgoA5CjmmYQDIUHju9Xm8fDUT0G7es4ZY13LKGWwrNsicmM6vKozsGagR6lZMMWiaqLAIxU8mngI1IeNyYWLJgBC3NjIgiIBvhkh4iwMdxGgHcLjzAh7uSB08ApviCW75D4QBh7dcJ7Ox/ngAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='/></td></tr><tr id='202111251128347740' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu("202111251128347740");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu("202111251128347740");'><td class='td_left noselect' nowrap='nowrap' align='right' draggable='false' ><IMG class='theimage' draggable='false' src='C:\Users\kjanky\AppData\Local\Viva_Client\387608\History\ThumbProfPics\RoundWithoutStatus\387283.png'></td><td class='td_center' id='Forward202111251128347740' style='table-layout:fixed;'><div class='noselect' style='color: DarkGray; text-align:left; font-size: 11px; '>khaled, 11:28 AM</div><div  id='menu202111251128347740' class='bubble-left' oncontextmenu='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2","تت", "202111251128347740");' ><P style='table-layout:fixed;  text-align:right;'>تت </p></div><div style='float:right;'><img id='pnt202111251128347740' class='noselect' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAFtJREFUKFNj+P//P8kYq2BuXqEAEAdgkwNhrIJADReA+D8ujRgCIAxUnADVKIBNHkOAGIxVkCyboBpI9hNZoQfSVIBNDoSxCgI1wJyHVSOGAAgDFdMpyPHj/wwAaF7b+svPFkkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;'  onclick='window.external.Menu("pointMenu#2", "تت", "202111251128347740");' /></div></td><td style='width:17px;' valign='top' align='left'><img style='margin-top: 3px;visibility:hidden;display:none;' id='read202111251128347740' draggable='false' class='noselect' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAAIRJREFUKFOVj0ERgDAMBCuhJvhXAhKQgAQkIAEJvFGBBCzgoA5CjmmYQDIUHju9Xm8fDUT0G7es4ZY13LKGWwrNsicmM6vKozsGagR6lZMMWiaqLAIxU8mngI1IeNyYWLJgBC3NjIgiIBvhkh4iwMdxGgHcLjzAh7uSB08ApviCW75D4QBh7dcJ7Ox/ngAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='/></td></tr><TR id='202111251128511144' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu("202111251128511144");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu("202111251128511144");'><td class='td_left' nowrap='nowrap' align='right' style='padding-top: 5px;'></td><td id='202111251128511144' class='td_center' style='table-layout:fixed;direction: ltr;' ><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' ><TR style='HEIGHT:10px; display: none;visibility: hidden;'><TD style='width:186px;' class='td_right'><div style='text-align:left; font-size: 11px;'>11:28 AM</div></TD><TD></TD></TR>
```

this is the JavaScript function that I try to execute and the table I want to append on

```
<script>
        function addMessageRowNew(html) {
                  
                    $('#tbl_body').append(html); 
                   
                } 
</script>
    <body class="aaa" dir="ltr" lang="en" style="font-size: 12px;font-family: 'Tahoma';" ondragover="allowDrop(event);" ondragstart="return false;">
        <div id="containerDiv" style="border:double; background-color:white; "><!--position:relative;height: 100%;-->
            <img id="page-background" src="" width="100%" height="100%">
            <!--<div style="position:absolute; bottom:5px;" >-->
                <table style="TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed;"  id="container">
            <!--<table id="container" border="1" style="overflow:scroll;"-->
                <tr>
                    <td valign="bottom">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="7" id="tbl_body">
                            <!--id="mcs-top"-->
                            <!--<tr style='height:27px;'>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" class='td_left' id='test'> Omar Maghmoumeh </td>
                        <td class='td_center'> Hello World </td>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" class='td_right'> 11:10 </td>
                    </tr>-->
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <!--</div>-->
        </div>
        <!--<div id="ChatInputBox">
            <div id="ChatInputBox-content">
                <//input id="Text1" name="Text1" type="text" value="Text1Value" />
            </div>
        </div>-->
    
    
    
    </body>
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? Why do you call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);`? - you already have a string, isn't that JSON ?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I can't call func from c# using executescriptAsync, but when I type the exact string in html it been called regularly @rfmodulator